# wsdl2java jaxws binding failing - possible XPATH issue

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm trying to autogenerate code from a wsdl and I was getting the following error:

Parameter: body already exists for method healthCheck1

I tried adding a custom bindings file but for some reason it's not working.

---

**The relevant sections of the WSDL:**

```
<wsdl:message name="transactionInfo">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="tsxsd:transactionInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="userIdentity">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="tsxsd:userIdentity"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="applicationInfo">
  <wsdl:part name="body" element="tsxsd:applicationInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:binding name="FinancialIndexConstituents_2_SoapBinding" type="FinancialIndexConstituents_2_port">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="HealthCheck_1">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.ws.com/soapaction?type=HealthCheck_1_Request&amp;ns=http://www.ws.webservices.com/FinancialIndexConstituents_2_HealthCheck_1"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="transactionInfo" part="body" use="literal" wsdl:required="false"/>
            <soap:header message="userIdentity" part="body" use="literal" wsdl:required="false"/>
        <soap:header message="applicationInfo" part="body" use="literal" wsdl:required="false"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="DefaultTornadoFault_1">
            <soap:fault name="DefaultTornadoFault_1" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
        <wsdl:fault name="NDAFault_1">
            <soap:fault name="NDAFault_1" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Standard_1">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.ws.com/soapaction?type=FinancialIndexConstituents_2_Standard_1_Request&amp;ns=http://www.ws.webservices.com/FinancialIndexConstituents_2_Standard_1"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="transactionInfo" part="body" use="literal" wsdl:required="false"/>
            <soap:header message="userIdentity" part="body" use="literal" wsdl:required="false"/>
            <soap:header message="applicationInfo" part="body" use="literal" wsdl:required="false"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="DefaultTornadoFault_1">
            <soap:fault name="DefaultTornadoFault_1" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
        <wsdl:fault name="NDAFault_1">
            <soap:fault name="NDAFault_1" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

**My bindings file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" 
                xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                wsdlLocation="FinancialIndexConstituents_2.wsdl">
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='FinancialIndexConstituents_2_port']/wsdl:operation[@name='HealthCheck_1']">
        <jaxws:parameter 
            part="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message[@name='transactionInfo']/wsdl:part[@name='body']" name="healthCheckTransInfoBody" />
        <jaxws:parameter 
            part="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message[@name='userIdentity']/wsdl:part[@name='body']" name="healthCheckUserIdBody" />
        <jaxws:parameter 
            part="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message[@name='applicationInfo']/wsdl:part[@name='body']" name="healthCheckAppInfobody" />
    </jaxws:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

I believe I might have some sort of XPATH problem, because with this bindings file I'm now getting the following error:

Parameter: healthCheckAppInfobody already exists for method healthCheck1 but of type java.lang.Object instead of TransactionInfo.  Use a JAXWS/JAXB binding customization to rename the parameter.

I would expect it would apply healthCheckTransInfoBody to that structure.